# Find all $x$ such that $x^{35} + 5x^{19} + 11x^3$ is divisible by 17.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function, euler-product

> Find all $x$ such that $x^{35} + 5x^{19} + 11x^3$ is divisible by 17.

I think we can use the fact that we can mod everything by 17 and want 0. But how exactly should we go about doing this?

Comment: Hint: $x^{35} = (x^{17})^2 \cdot x \equiv x^2 \cdot x = x^3 \pmod{17}$ and similarly $x^{19} \equiv x^3 \pmod{17}$.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}x^{35}+5x^{19}+11x^3
&= x^{17}\cdot x^{17} \cdot x + 5 x^{17}\cdot x^2 + 11 x^3\\
&\equiv x\cdot x \cdot x + 5x \cdot x^2 + 11 x^3 \;(\mathrm{mod}\;17)
= 17x^3\\
&\equiv 0\;(\mathrm{mod}\; 17)
\end{align}
where we apply Fermat's little theorem a few times ($a^p \equiv a \;(\mathrm{mod}\; p)$). Therefore it works for all integers $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{17}+5x^{19}+11x^3=(x^{18}+6x^2)(x^{17}-x)+17x^3$$

Since $x^{17}-x$ is divisible by $17$ and so is $17x^3$, so is the original polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Any integer value for $x$ will do !

Observe that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17} 
\end{eqnarray*}
and the expression can be written as $x^3(11+5x^{16}+x^{32})$ so the bracket will always be divisible by $17$.

Answer (score 1):

*Lil' Fermat* says this is the same as solving the equation in the field $\mathbf Z/17\mathbf Z$
$$x\cdot (x^{17})^2+5x^{17}\cdot x^2+11x^3+=(1+5+11)x^3=0.$$

Thus the given expression is divisible by $17$  for all  $x$.

Comment: 2 other users stated the expression is divisible for any integer x. Which is true?

Comment: @JohnLocke (from David Hume…): I'll check my computation.

Comment: @JohnLocke: Checked. I had  erroneously applied Fermat for one exponent (it's beginning to be late…). Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}{\rm mod}\ 17\!:\,\ x\not\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large 16}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, &\ x^{\large\color{#c00}{n}}\equiv\, x^{\large\color{#c00}{ n\bmod 16}}\ \ \text{by little Fermat, hence}\\[.3em]
&\ x^{\large\color{#c00}{35}}\!+5 x^{\large\color{#0a0}{19}}\!+ 11 x^{\large 3}\\[.2em]
\equiv\ &\  x^{\large\color{#c00}3}\ + 5 x^{\large\color{#0a0}3} +\, 11 x^{\large 3}\ \ \,{\rm by}\,\ \ {\rm mod}\ 16\!:\ \color{#c00}{35\equiv 3},\ \color{#0a0}{19\equiv 3}\\[.2em]
\equiv\  & 17x^{\large 3}\equiv\, 0
\end{align}$